# How to decrypt username and password which is encrypted by Kinvey

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, encryption, kinvey

When i make GET ajax request from postmam, i recieve these things:

"username": "868e7a59-d76f-42e5-8500-b59a3efe262b",
  "password": "a269ddce-69f2-4f16-94c1-038b2a1e1092"

The question is: How can y decrypt the username and password ?

Comment: These look like GUIDs, rather than encryption.

Comment: Maybe they are keys to remote credentials?

Comment: How can i find these keys Ross ?

Comment: Maybe you can't. Perhaps they can only be overwritten.

Comment: My task is when i create new users, i should see their usernames and passwords. How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Username: That is actually the real username. If you do not specify a username in your login or create request, then Kinvey will assign a random identifier. This is what you see. Can you share your SDK code for creating a user?

Password: One-way hash that you cannot decrypt.

Also: If you have a js framework, please do not use direct REST calls but intsead use our javascript SDK's (e.g. angular, html5, phonegap, etc.)

Comment: So there isn't way in which i can see the password in given user in Kinvey ?